# ggplot2 facet_grid() change background-color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a graph like in the image below using `facet_grid()` to group the different graphs. Now I want to make the graph prettier and want to change the background color of right side. But the only thing I found was `opts(strip.text.y = theme_text(hjust = 0))` that can change the color of the text.

So, it is possible to change the background color of the right part? I tried to make it more understandable with the image below.

Best regards!

[image: what I want displayed in an image ;-)]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Untested, try to change the outline:

```
+ opts(strip.background = theme_rect(colour = 'purple'))
```

at the end of your qplot / ggplot2 code. And in case you did not know: [this Link](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Faceting-Attributes) to Hadley's reference on github (not documentation) might help.

EDIT:

thanks to Jonathan, I realized the following works, the upper snippet just changes the outline. This one is for the fill:

```
+ opts(strip.background = theme_rect(fill = 'purple'))
```

Maybe that has been changed by Hadley?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know the site before. Also thanks for your code sample, it works!

Comment: Minor correction: "colour" is for the outline of the box, you should use "fill" to change the background.

Comment: @Jonathan I would have thought that too, but "colour" works for me "fill" doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: hmm guess there's been a change to ggplot. Now that I try it, I see it's exactly like Jonathan suggests. Maybe that was different when Sarah and shujaa tried. Long story short: By today, Jonathan is definitely right!

Comment: new syntax: strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'purple')

Comment: Hi, I have used 'fill' and 'colour' and no change, any idea? Thanks!!